# I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException error while running my project which has Testng framework configured with ATUReporter

Tags: java, maven

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException error while running my project which has Testng framework configured with ATUReporter as below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.invokeListeners(SuiteRunner.java:201)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at atu.testng.reports.utils.Directory.init(Unknown Source)
    at atu.testng.reports.utils.Directory.verifyRequiredFiles(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
```

Things I have done

1. Added the ATU jars in lib folder of project
2. Added dependency in pom.xml.
3. The sytemPath is set correctly in pom.xml where the ATU jars are added

   ${project.basedir}/lib/jar/ATUTestRecorder_2.1.jar

   ${project.basedir}/lib/ATUReporter_Selenium_testNG_5.1.1.jar
4. Added ATU listners on testng.xml

```
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" /> 
        <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener" />
        <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ConfigurationListener" />
        <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.MethodListener" />
```

Comment: You may need to debug and see what is the cause of the NPE.

Comment: I would like to add the point that this is maven project. I have cleaned the maven and updated too. This issue encountered at initial stage.